# Inserting Form feed/Page break data in MS-SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some textual data which comprises of form feed characters (`FF`) as I see in Notepad++. I need to insert this data into a MS-SQL table cell.

I created a table with `nvarchar` datatype and tried adding this data, but it didn't work. I then redesigned the table and tried using the `text` datatype, but it still didn't work.

Any ideas on how I can insert data of this sort into a SQL table?

Please consider the data somewhat like the this:

```
Alex Smith
FF
John Doe
FF
Smith Jones
FF
```

Comment: Have you tried doing an INSERT from SQL Server Management Studio? If so, what were the results and/or error messages?

Comment: Also, how are you verifying that it didn't work? Form feeds are not visible, so are you pulling your data back out and looking at it in a text editor, or trying to print it or...?

Comment: I am sorry. My bad. It worked. I was inserting using the edit option of MSSQL and it wasn't working. I then wrote a simple T-SQL to insert the same data with FF and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.  You will need to use the line feed character in SQL

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/22/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-insert-carriage-return-and-new-line-feed-in-code/